# Angular Material - Menu's "addItem" Method Not Registering Custom Components

Tags: angular-material

I already asked this question on Angular Material's [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/16753) and I followed their instructions in this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vud6ag?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fmenu-item%2Fmenu-item.component.html). However I still can't make it work.

The problem is as follows:

I updated @angular/material from 8.0.2 to 8.1.2 and my custom menu component stopped working with the keyboard.

The problem seems to be that in *node_modules/@angular/material/esm2015/menu.js* the addItem method is empty.

**Version 8.1.2** *node_modules/@angular/material/esm2015/menu.js*

```
    /*
       * Registers a menu item with the menu.
       * @docs-private
       * @deprecated No longer being used. To be removed.
       * @breaking-change 9.0.0
       */
    /**
     * @param {?} _item
     * @return {?}
     */
    addItem(_item) {}
```

**Version 8.0.2** *node_modules/@angular/material/esm2015/menu.js*

```
addItem(_item) {
    if (this._items.indexOf(item) === -1) {
        this._items.push(item);
        this._itemChanges.next(this._items);
    }
}
```

The code below worked before updating to 8.1.2

```
// MenuComponent
@ViewChild('menu', { static: false }) menu: MatMenu;
@ContentChildren(MenuItemComponent) menuItems: QueryList<
    MenuItemComponent
>;
@ContentChildren(MenuItemComponent) menuItems: QueryList<
    MenuItemComponent
>;
this.menuItems.forEach(menuItem => {
  this.menu.addItem(menuItem.matMenuItem);
});
```

```
// MenuItemComponent
@ViewChild(MatMenuItem, {static: false}) matMenuItem: MatMenuItem
```

It would be highly appreciated if somebody could provide a working StackBlitz example in which you can use `Tab` to focus the menu, hit `Enter` to open it and use the arrow keys <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> to navigate all menu items!